# Implement one additional property from another table in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

```
public class Order() 
{
    public int ordernumId {get;set;}
    public int factoryId {get;set;}
}

public class Factory 
{
    public int factoryId {get;set;}
    public int factoryName {get;set;}
}
```

1. Only make one database call.
2. Factoryname and Ordercode on the same
   webpage.
3. Imagine there are 15 million other ViewModels which all
   want a similar

   ```
   Public Class Order_Details_VM 
   {
       public int ordernumId {get;set;}
       public int factoryName {get;set;}
   }
   ```

My layers are like so:
Views->ViewModels=>Controllers->Repository->EntityFramework

The repository is usually passing back IQueryable objects, but sometimes DTO or EF models (EF because the DTO is the same).

I'd like to here some suggestions which don't involve asking automapper to do this for the 15 million viewmodels via membership rules.

Oh and this is all in Japanese so auto-flattening doesn't work. :-)

How do I do this 'properly'?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Probably since model-to-viewmodel mappings are dynamically generated by AutoMapper like `Mapper.Map<Model, ViewModel>(list)` for type conversions, it might cost some performance overhead compared to manual class mappings on large databases. Consider `Order` & `Factory` are POCO objects, mapping method(s) on controller that have access to repository using dependency injection may applicable instead of using Automapper.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto You're saying to create a service which handles the mappings myself manually after it has pulled the DTO from the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to my own question here after I reread this with more exprerince.

The right way to do this is to map into larger DTO objects.

So for example, my `OrderDto` should contain `FactoryName` which may seem like a waste for many places where FactoryName isn't used in the view, but its barely any overhead to just include it by default so the database always joins and gets the Factory name.

So anytime any page wants to get anything to do with an Order, it will also have optional access to the `FactoryName`

*Domain Layer*

```
public class Order() 
{
    public int ordernumId {get;set;}
    public int factoryId {get;set;}
}

public class Factory 
{
    public int factoryId {get;set;}
    public int factoryName {get;set;}
}
```

*Application/Service Layer*

```
public class OrderDto() 
{
    public int ordernumId {get;set;}
    public int factoryId {get;set;}
    public int factoryName {get;set;}
}
```

*Presentation Layer*

```
public Class Order_Details_VM 
{
    public int ordernumId {get;set;}
    public int factoryName {get;set;}
}
```